# How can I make the index values display on the x-axis ticks?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, axis-labels

I am plotting data from a pandas dataframe that has a weekday names as the index. The plots look good; however, the x-axis does not show the weekdays (Monday through Sunday order). How can I get the days to display?

As shown in my code, I have attempted some workarounds found in other answers around the site, but all I have accomplished is getting the first (Monday) tick to appear with its label.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.xaxis.set_ticks([1])
ax1.xaxis.set_label_text(" ")
ax1.set_title(" item1 ", fontweight='bold')
avgs_df.loc[order,['item1']].plot(ax=ax1, legend=False)
```

Plot here:

[image]

The lines with the `.xaxis.set_ticks([1])` I do not fully understand, but have thus far been the only thing that has put a day label on the plot. Changing the value in the square brackets seems to print the same, single label on top of the first.

I am expecting to get all seven days on the plots' x-axis as ticks and labels.

The dataframe contains seven fields: Time (hour of the day), and six item fields with numbers 0:1. Looking at the head yields:

```py
avgs_df.head()
```

Image of output here (I don't have enough reputation): 
[image: img]

Answer (score 2):

`.xaxis.set_ticks([1])` set the ticks at position 1 only. That's why you have Monday only.

To have 7 ticks, you should pass something like `.xaxis.set_ticks(range(7))` (position starts from 0 usually, so `range(7)` produces the correct tick positions, from 0 to 6).

I'm not really sure what is the dataframe index here (your picture shows all Fridays), but if the index are the weekdays as I suspect, it should work even by simply removing the `.xaxis.set_ticks([1])` lines. `matplotlib` will put all of them automatically in the picture if there is enough space.

#### EDIT after comments

So you have 168 rows, one for each hour of the days of the week. If using `ax1.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0, 168, 24.0))` allows you to add just the ticks you want, you can set the text of the ticks by using:

```
ax1.set_xticklabels(["Monday", "Tuesday", ...]) #make a list of all days
```

Just adding this line after `.xaxis.set_ticks()` should be ok. Be sure to provide a list with the same length of the ticks.

If your dataframe indexes are the day names, you can instead use:

```
ax1.set_xticklabels(avgs_df.index[np.arange(0, 168, 24.0)])
```

to get the exact text of the index and place it as text of the ticks.

Comment: Yes, the dataframe does have entries for the other weekdays. Unfortunately, this answer did not work. I appears to print "Monday" seven times. There are 24 observations (one for each hour in the day). I think this answer may be having it print "Monday" at each hour's location. Ideally, having it print the day at hour 0:00 would be best for me. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Also, I did get the ticks located in the correct position with ```ax1.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0, 168, 24.0))``` seeing as there are 168 records corresponding to 24 hours in a day over 7 weekdays. If I could figure out how to get the weekdays to display...